# How to output a variable from dynamically created vba userform textbox

Tags: excel, userform, vba

hopefully I am asking the correct question.  I have a userform that displays X number of text boxes when initialized. here is a snippet:

```
Dim MF As Object

Set MF = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "BoxNumber_" & i, True)
    With MF
        .Value = ""
    End With
```

`??? msgbox Me.MF.BoxNumber_i.value`

Once a user is finished filling out the userform it will eventually write the results to SQL.  my question is.. how do I output the variable MF.BoxNumber_i.value once the user fills this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, figured I would post the solution in case someone stumbles across this one day.

`msgbox Me.Controls("BoxNumber" & i).value`